# Serial port string recognision

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

I'm having incoming data recieved over a serial port, with a serial port reader that sits there and reads all data. I want the following to happen:

When ENTER ("\r") is being received over the serial port, I want the line of data before the ENTER captured in a string, and its first letter compared with the first letter that comes after the ENTER. If they match, continue reading the serial, if they don't, then display the line of text.

Here's my solution in C#. It doesn't work and I suspect some logic errors:

```
public void SerialReceived_Uson()
        {
            // create a temporary storage string 
            string sTemp = "";
            // add buffer to string (sCurrent)
            sRecievedString += comPort.ReadExisting();
            // when the last member in string is Carriage return copy the string to a     temporary location (sTemp)
            if (sRecievedString.EndsWith("\r"))
            {
                sTemp = sRecievedString;
                // clear string 
                sRecievedString = "";

            }
                // add new buffer to the string
                sRecievedString += comPort.ReadExisting();
                // compare the starting characters of the two strings
                if (sRecievedString[0] == sTemp[0])
                {
                    // if they match, override sTemp with sCurrent and continue reading 
                    sTemp = sRecievedString;
                    sRecievedString += comPort.ReadExisting();
                }
                // else display sTemp
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(sTemp);

                } 
        }
```

Comment: Please, can you define "it doesn't work" ? You explain what you expect, but what do you actually obtain ?

Comment: It doesn't work as in - it doesn't show up the messageBox. I've described what I'm expecting here:

"if they match, continue reading the serial, if they don't, then display the line of text."

Comment: My comment was mainly aimed at trying to figure out what specific part of your code might be at fault. I hope you can understand that trying to understand your problem without having all the knowledge that you do can be difficult. It's up to you if you want to provide more information when requested to. If not, then I don't think people will be very interested in helping you.

Comment: Hey, I didn't want to be rude or anything, sorry if that's you understood!!!

What more do you need to know ? When I execute this code, no messagebox appears on screen, although I know that "\r" has been sent through the serial port.

Comment: Well, for example, when you call ReadExisting(), are you actually sure that the whole line is buffered ? Also, what class is comPort ? Is it .NET SerialPort ? Also, is the above method part of an Event Handler ?

Comment: 1. Not sure, I don't fully understand how ReadExisting work. It's a method part of the Io.Port class. 
2. Yes
3. Yes, it's triggered by a function OpenPort( ). If this is true, and the COM port is opened, my function is executed. I've tested the event handler and it works, so it has to be something wrong with the way I've written this function.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong.  Calling ReadExisting() more than once doesn't accomplish anything.  The simple solution is to set the SerialPort.NewLine property to "\r" and calling ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting().